# How to create a new dataframe using two existing dataframes?

Tags: r

I have 2 dataframes:

```
stats_20 = data.frame(name = c('Abby', 'Ben', 'Casey'), goals = c(4, 6, 3), assists = c(3, 2, 5))
stats_21 = data.frame(name = c('Abby', 'Ben', 'David'), goals = c(3, 3, 8), assists = c(2, 5, 4))
```

I want to combine the two into a "Total" dataframe similar to:

```
total_stats
   name      goals     assists
1  Abby          7           5
2  Ben           9           7
3  David         8           4
```

I don't care about names that don't appear in stat_21 (e.g., Casey).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to aggregate the two then use dplyr and do something like:

```
rbind( stats_20, stats_21 ) %>% group_by( names ) %>% summarize( gl = sum(goals) , ass=sum(assists) )
```

If you need to first get rid of anything in stats_21 that isn't in stats_20 then look at `dplyr::outer_join` to see how to flag the records to delete.